# Upload path on Codeigniter returns "the upload path doesn't seem to be valid"

Tags: php, codeigniter

Now i've tried most of the fixes that i've read, most of them mention about APPPATH, base_url(), real path and etc. but i really don't know why all of them didn't work, what worked for me is that i've used the actual path, not a url but the one with the C:\xampp\htdocs.. blah blah blah.. now i've read one thread that url and directory aren't the same thing.. and the upload_path accepts only directory path and i mean the actual location of the uploads folder on the server not the URL.. now my question is how come APPPATH don't work. as what i know it the actual directory path. but when i tried to display is it return only "../applicaiton/" what really is the best path to be used on the $config['upload_path'] on the upload.php specially when deploying it to an actual server it is really a nuisance finding the directory path of your upload folder, NOTE im not using the initialize() method i'm putting my configs on config/upload.php

EDITS:

i have this on a separate file... upload.php

```
<?php 
$config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '5000';
$config['max_width'] = '1600';
$config['max_height'] = '1200';
```

and this is my controller

```
     if($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
     {
         //Did something here
     }
     else
     {
        //Did something for errors like display_errors()
     }
```

and end result is it displays "the upload path doesn't seem to be valid"
and i've tried these line of code also

Trial 1:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/';
```

Trial 2:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='uploads/';
```

Trial 3:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='/admin/assets/uploads/';
```

Trial 4:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='./admin/assets/uploads/';
```

Trial 5:

```
$config['upload_path'] ='admin/assets/uploads/';
```

the only thing that works is this

```
 $config['upload_path'] ='C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\admin.abcgencon\admin\assets\uploads'';
```

and using the last part as a path is kinda messy so i've tried also `APPPATH`but it doesn't work also it also display "../application"..

as @cryptic said i've posted this code snippet.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, so i'm pasting how file uploading is done in CI in the answer below

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Question, you tried `realpath` and `APPPATH` seperately?

In Codeigniter `APPPATH` points to the application folder.

**Example**: (place your folder outside the application folder, just saying if you did not do that way) let's say the folder where we want to place the files called **images**.

So what you need to do is to combine `realpath(`) and `APPPATH`

```
$image_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
```

and pass it to your config

```
$config['upload_path'] = $image_path;
```

Comment: nope here is my folder tree application, system, admin under admin is assets under assets is the uploads

Comment: btw is realpath native to php or to CI ?

Comment: realpath is native to php, than point it to the folder tree what you told trying what i posted :)

Comment: ohhh this helps me alot man.. more cleaner than copying the actual path :D though can u explain to me why did you combined both?

Comment: because of the dots, its not really ideal so realpath cleans it up and reaturns the real full path of that folder

Answer (score 1):

Create your file upload directory say uploads outside of application directory or at the root directory of CI, and set the upload path as follows:-

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(FCPATH.'uploads');
```

> FCPATH: Path to the front controller where index.php exists (root of CI)

The above code runs on both server and local.

Comment: Thank you. This Works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how file uploading is done in CI

```
$cat_image_name = $_FILES["cat_image"]["name"] ; 

//file uploading params
$config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/categories';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name'] = $image_id."_ipad";
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

//Loading Library - File Uploading
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//Upload the image(Ipad)
if (!empty($cat_image_name)) 
{
  $this->upload->do_upload('cat_image');
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
  $category_image_ipad = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
  $img_extension = $data['upload_data']['file_ext'];
}
```

Comment: does defining $config on a separte file like upload.php and putting it in config/ and defining it on a controller the same?

Comment: You don't have to have it in another file. Why don't you define the $config['upload_path'] in the controller?

Comment: Files you uploaded should be uploaded outside the application folder

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$config['upload_path'] = '../uploads/;
```

It's working very well for me

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/";
//$this->config->item('upload_path');
```

Answer (score 0):

file upload requires a multipart form. For this, you must have included a form helper.

goto config folder, click autoload and find the `$autoload['helper'] = array();` and put 'form' :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

for controller:

$config = array(

```
    'upload_path' => "./assets/",
    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "2048000",
    'max_height' => "768",
    'max_width' => "1024"
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    }

    $this->user_model->create_photo($post_image);
    redirect('');
}
```

for model:

```
public function create_photo($post_image){

    $data = array(
        'pri' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'descrip' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'post_image' => $post_image
    );

    return $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows & Linux:

```
$path = realpath(".");
$path .= "/uploads/profile_images";
```

Here uploads is the uploads directory on root.

Answer (score 0):

**FCPATH:** front controller path where index.php exists or **root** folder

**APPPATH:** **application** folder

Create a **uploads** folder under **root** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(FCPATH.'uploads');
```

Create a **uploads** folder under **application** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'uploads');
```

In case: If you have created the **uploads** folder outside of **root** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads');
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple:

Just copy your all $config in new php file called upload.php and put it in cofig folder.

You path will work ok.

Here is upload.php file contents:

```
<?php

    $config['upload_path'] = site_url().'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|html|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = 0;
    $config['max_width']  = 0;
    $config['max_height']  = 0;
    $config['file_ext_tolower']  = TRUE;
    $config['overwrite']  = FALSE;
    $config['max_filename']  = 0;
    $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;
    $config['detect_mime']  = TRUE;
    $config['mod_mime_fix']  = TRUE;
?>
```

But please keep $config data in upload_file controller as well.For example:

```
public function do_upload(){

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|html|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = 0;
    $config['max_width']  = 0;
    $config['max_height']  = 0;
    $config['file_ext_tolower']  = TRUE;
    $config['overwrite']  = FALSE;
    $config['max_filename']  = 0;
    $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
    $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;
    $config['detect_mime']  = TRUE;
    $config['mod_mime_fix']  = TRUE;

//Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:

   $this->upload->initialize($config);


            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
    }
```

It is simple...

Comment: Why would someone want to duplicate code in two places?