# Codeigniter , The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm have a problem uploading a picture using codeigniter. I followed the online upload tutorial, but can't figure out the problem. I keep getting "The upload path does not appear to be valid". So, here's my form structure:

```
<?php if (isset($error)) {?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <?= $error ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('pages/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

I also checked for my directory to be a valid path and to be writable with this code:

```
<?php if(is_writable('./uploads') && is_dir('./uploads')){
echo 'valid';
}
else { echo  (base_url('uploads'). ' ' ."is not writable");} ?>
```

And this returns valid.

The following is my controller structure:

```
public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000000000;
            $config['max_width']            = 1920;
            $config['max_height']           = 1080;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('user/profile/profile', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
```

In construct i loaded the upload library. 
With all this being said, I keep getting the error I mentioned before.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050322/upload-path-on-codeigniter-returns-the-upload-path-doesnt-seem-to-be-valid

Comment: Thanks, now this is fun. I used the syntax 
    $image_path = realpath(APPPATH . '.uploads');
                $config['upload_path']          = $image_path;
And now the error i get is another: The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable. But I created it with command line as: "chmod 777 foldername"

Comment: give permission again recursive

Comment: I deleted and created the folder again with "mkdir 777 uploads" but still is not writable

Comment: are you sure that you change permission of the folder which system are pointing to upload?

Comment: I'm running a docker container with apache, and in the container I opened the exec window and created the folder from there... The container is called lamp... And just to be sure I allowed also form my mac admin profile all priviledge to the folder (everyone can write and read) ...

Comment: try with base64

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
$config["upload_path"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your/desired/location/";
```

Comment: I solved the upload path problem, but after solving it another one appeared... read the other comments in the question if you feel like helping me in that issue too :)