# The uploaded file didn't go to the upload folders for CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've successfully implemented the models for handling file uploads in my project. However, even though the file upload process is functional, I've encountered an issue where the uploaded file isn't being directed to the intended destination, specifically the /resources/uploads/ directory.

```
public function tambahTTD()
    {
        $this->load->model('pic_model');
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $token =  sha1(random_string('alnum', 20));
        $created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $config['cacheable']    = true; //boolean, the default is true
        $config['cachedir']     = './resources/qrcode/cachedir/'; //string, the default is application/cache/
        $config['errorlog']     = './resources/qrcode/errorlog/'; //string, the default is application/logs/
        $config['imagedir']     = './resources/qrcode/imagedir/'; //direktori penyimpanan qr code
        $config['quality']      = true; //boolean, the default is true
        $config['size']         = '1024'; //interger, the default is 1024
        $config['black']        = array(224, 255, 255); // array, default is array(255,255,255)
        $config['white']        = array(70, 130, 180); // array, default is array(0,0,0)
        $this->ciqrcode->initialize($config);

        $image_name = $token . '.png'; //buat name dari qr code sesuai dengan nim

        $params['data'] = site_url() . 'token_check/verify/' . $token; //data yang akan di jadikan QR CODE
        $params['level'] = 'H'; //H=High
        $params['size'] = 10;
        $params['savename'] = FCPATH . $config['imagedir'] . $image_name; //simpan image QR CODE ke folder assets/images/

        $config['upload_path']          = APPPATH . '../resources/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size']             = 100;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        //get the uploaded file name
        $data['pic_file'] = $upload_data['file_name'];

        //store pic data to the db
        $this->ciqrcode->generate($params); // fungsi untuk generate QR CODE
        $data = [
            'token' => $token,
            'id' => $this->input->post('id', TRUE),
            'id_nip' => $this->input->post('nip', TRUE),
            'id_jenis_ttd' => $this->input->post('jenis_ttd', TRUE),
            'keterangan' => $this->input->post('keterangan', TRUE),
            'tgl_awal' => $this->input->post('tgl_awal', TRUE),
            'tgl_akhir' => $this->input->post('tgl_akhir', TRUE),
            'edited_by' => $this->input->post('edited_by', TRUE),
            'qrcode' => 'resources/qrcode/imagedir/' . $image_name,
            'created_on' => $created_on,
            'pic_file' => $this->input->post('pic_file', TRUE), // 

        $this->db->insert('ttd', $data);
```

```
I need to solve this line to fix that, or some of you have best solution for me.
```

> $config['upload_path']          = APPPATH . '../resources/uploads/';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload path on Codeigniter returns "the upload path doesn't seem to be valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050322/upload-path-on-codeigniter-returns-the-upload-path-doesnt-seem-to-be-valid)